# My routing doesn't work when I try to refresh an existing page

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have done my routing using angular 7 and it works fine if I follow the path using my menu key. But if I am on a page and tries to refresh the browser it gives me 404 error. Similary I cannot directly access any single page, I have to go to all pages using the buttons. 
Example of my code:
this is part of my routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',component:Component1
  },
  {
    path: 'home', component: Component2
  }]
```

my index has bas ref as:

```
<base href="/myforms/">
```

and I am accessing the component2 using the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
              <a routerLink="home" router-link-Active="active" ><button class="btn btn-green">Home</button></a>              
            </div>
```

and it works fine I get the url: localhost:8091/myforms/home and it opens when I click the button. But if I refresh my page it gives me 404.

Kindly help me if you know anything regarding this issue. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: See [Routed apps must fallback to index.html](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml).

Comment: How does your URL look like after/while refreshing? Probably you got to do a rewrite on the serverside because you need to return the index.html on any request (besides AJAX) so that the router can examine the URL config at an initial pageload. This is a typical SPA Routing issue/behaviour. You dont need to rewrite if you use Hashbang URLS /!#/... You can activate it in Angular....! Please check your HTTP Traffic to realise the issue!

Comment: Hey Okyo, Thankyou for your response. My url look like the same. When I open the page initially its localhost:8091/myforms/ and after I click the button it changes to localhost:8091/myforms/home and the home page opens but if I refresh the browser it gives me 404 error with same url. like I can't directly open my home page but I have to go from myforms

Comment: Can you help me how can I do the settings so it allows the refresh option? Thankyou in advance @Okyo

Comment: What server do you use? 
Please rewrite your request, so  that your server will respond with the index.html. You get a 404 because your client sends a HTTP Request: GET myforms/home to the server! But your server does not know the myforms/home route because there is no home.html file. As your server does not own this file, it respond with 404 Page Not Found!  If building a SPA based on router the solution is to rewrite this request:

GET /myforms/home should return index.html ... pleas check out the linke above from @insertusernamehere

Comment: I have a spring/angular full stack application. Can you tell me where exactly I need to change the settings in order to load the index.html file first? Sorry if my question sounds stupid but I am new to angular @Okyo

Comment: Please find out how to URL Rewrite in Spring/Spring Boot. You either maybe use the deployment descriptor web.xml or use Programmatic-Servlet-Mapping!

1. Looks kind of <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

2. Looks kind of: ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
ServletRegistration sr = sc.addServlet("index", "BusinessServlets.Index");
sr.addMapping("/");

This issue is not specially related to Angular!